# Problem with smart contract deployment

Tags: solidity, mist, contract-deployment, truffle-compile

I have compiled test crowdsale smart contract with inheriting from other contracts( like TestToken is MintableToken). The main smart contract consists only of one file, where I described all inheritances, but after compilation, I received many compiled files. How I must to deploy they to network? Or I need to deploy only one smart contract, named "TestTokenCrowdsale"? With Truffle all seems good. But Mist proposes to me to select which smart contract I must to deploy. And i don't know how to be. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you use truffle you need to create the migration, you can deploy contract with migration. If you want to see tutorial of simple dapp here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FYGSYZSJYg&t=1282s

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is normal for Mist to propose which contract to deploy when you provide the source code in a single file. You just need to select TestTokenCrowdsale.